# How to scale text on a texture (quad object)?

Tags: java, android, math, graphics, opengl-es

I have found a good way to draw text in openGL by creating a Bitmap, drawing text on it, and making it into a texture.

I have screenCoordinates(320,~~480) and gameCoordinates(20,28), in which quads' dimensions are defined. Example constructor: `GameObject(x, y, width, height, text)`.

To create the bitmap I create a Canvas with this size:

```
// get width and height in px (p is a Paint() object)
    p.setTextSize(textSize * Main.getMainResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    final int width = (int) p.measureText(text);
    final int height = (int) (p.descent() + -p.ascent());

canvas.drawText(text, 0, -p.ascent(), p);
```

Create a bitmap of this, scaled to the next power of 2, and you have your texture-bitmap.

However the problem is that because the quad's dimensions are not adapted to the bitmap(text) dimensions, the text isn't very smooth. I have the possibility to change the quad's dimensions with `quad.setDimensions(width, height)`, but what would be the size I'd have to give it, and also shouldn't I also have to worry about the textSize(sp) of the text i'm drawing?

This all is in 2D, and some simple math's might get involved, but how should I get the right dimensions?